# Putting two legend labels in different location in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have three plots merged with one another in one figure that contain a lot of notable information. I recently was able to color code the legend labels instead of having them be labeled with their associated lines.

[image]

But when I try to add another set of labels in another location on one of the plots, the original disappears

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.ticker as tic
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig111 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3, width_ratios=[1,1,0.3]) 
Bind = fig111.add_subplot(gs[0])
BindD = fig111.add_subplot(gs[1], sharey=Bind)
Hist = fig111.add_subplot(gs[2], sharey=BindD)

...
...

empty = Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, alpha=0.0)

l = Bind.legend([empty], ['Illustris-1'], 
      loc='upper left', frameon=False, handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)
lD = BindD.legend([empty], ['Illustris-1-Dark'], 
        loc='upper left', frameon=False, handlelength=0, 
handletextpad=0)

dw = Bind.legend([empty,empty,empty,empty], ['Carina', 'Sculptor', 'Ursa Minor', 'Leo I' ], 
       loc='center right', frameon=False, handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)

l.get_texts()[0].set_color('slateblue')
lD.get_texts()[0].set_color('crimson')

dw.get_texts()[0].set_color('mediumspringgreen')
dw.get_texts()[1].set_color('orchid')
dw.get_texts()[2].set_color('c')
dw.get_texts()[3].set_color('orange')

gs.update(wspace=0)
plt.setp([BindD.get_yticklabels() ,Hist.get_yticklabels()], visible=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

What is a efficient way to have both labels on the same subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the chapter [Multiple legends on the same axes](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes) of the matplotlib legend guide, you need to add the first legend as an artist to the axes before creating the second one

```
legend = Bind.legend(...)
Bind.add_artist(legend)
Bind.legend(...)
```